# AngularJs Replace Image Content

Tags: angularjs

There is an image I want to display that depends on the response of a POST request.

```
<img ng-src="executePost()">
```

This is the controller.

```
$scope.executePost = function() {
    $http.post('/post', {'data':'reallylongstuffthatcantbedonewithget'}).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }, function(data, status){});
}
```

The response (i.e. console.log(result)) is a image/png type. How can I replace the image with the one returned via the POST request? Do I have to send the image back base64 encoded or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would perform a get on the image url if the post returns success.
The base64 solution seems a way of achieving your goal, but I'd think a post isn't meant to retrieve data.